# Why does `dnf updateinfo` just output the "Last metadata expiration check"

Tags: linux, centos, yum, dnf

I am writing a program to control dnf, and it needs a list of available updates for further processing.

The command `dnf updateinfo` seems what I want, I tried it on CentOS 8 Stream, but it just outputs this:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:24:03 ago on Tue 09 Feb 2021 07:51:05 PM CST.
```

am I missing anything?

By the way, I want to know if there is a better way to do it with dnf?

Comment: Can't test this at the moment, but you migh want something like `dnf check-update`?

Comment: @BulletBob 
Thanks a lot, `dnf check-update` could be used to check if updates available and output the list of updates.

I still want to try with `dnf updateinfo`，because it supports more arguments to get a different type of update.